# Robocopy with volume id paths?

Tags: windows-server-2008, robocopy

Is it possible to use robocopy with volume id paths?

```
C:\>robocopy /MIR /COPYALL /R:0 \\?\Volume{8a20c0df-ba3-44e9-8529-e6cd231a6759}\ \\?\Volume{3f1c91a3-39c0-11e6-a9fc-000c29ac2558}\

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Jun 24 13:32:25 2016

   Source : \\?\Volume{8a20c0df-0ba3-44e9-8529-e6cd231a6759}\
     Dest : \\?\Volume{3f1c91a3-39c0-11e6-a9fc-000c29ac2558}\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPYALL /PURGE /MIR /R:0 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016/06/24 13:32:27 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Source Directory \\?\Volume{8a20c0df-0ba3-44e9-8529-e6cd231a6759}\
The network path was not found.

2016/06/24 13:32:27 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Source Directory \\?\Volume{8a20c0df-0ba3-44e9-8529-e6cd231a6759}\
The network path was not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not - direct usage of Volume ID's is typically not supported.

You could always start with a

```
MountVol.exe
```

command to map to a drive, then proceed from there.